# De Jquery a Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

quisiera saber cómo queda este código de Jquery a Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav-icon').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    $(".overlay").toggleClass("open");
    $(".overlay a").toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hola Dinora, sería ideal si pudieras editar la pregunta para añadir algo más de información: ¿qué has intentado hasta el momento? ¿con qué problemas o dificultades te estás encontrando? Lee [ask] y completa el [tour] para más información (y para ganar una nueva medalla).

Answer (score 0):

Quedaría algo así:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var object1 = document.getElementById('nav-icon');
    object1.addEventListener("click", function(){
         object1.classList.add("open");
         document.getElementsByClassName('overlay').forEach(function(el){
              el.classList.add("open");
         });
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: Esto no hace lo mismo que el código expuesto en la pregunta. Faltaría cambiar la clase de los `a`, además `toggleClass` no solo añade sino que también quita si la clase está ya.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de como lo haria yo:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
  document.querySelector('#nav-icon').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.target.classList.toggle('open');
  document.querySelector('.overlay').classList.toggle('open');
  document.querySelector('.overlay a').classList.toggle('open');
  });
});
```

```css
.open{
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<button id="nav-icon">boton</button>
<div class="overlay"><a>ddddd</a></div>
</html>
```